# SQL-Error [IX000]: Connection not established (Informix / DBeaver)

Tags: database, informix, dbeaver

I got the following error in the database manager DBeaver 22.1.4 on the informix database:

> SQL-Error [IX000]: Connection not established

Strangely if i make a select only on this table i got the error above. But if i make a select on all other tables the select has an result.

The full error message you find here:

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL-Error [IX000]: Connection not established
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:1)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.createStatement(DBUtils.java:1391)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.makeStatement(DBUtils.java:1359)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:553)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:486)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:493)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:894)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3643)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:118)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:116)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4945)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:416)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:397)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:371)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.<init>(IfxStatement.java:134)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.<init>(IfxPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(IfxSqliConnect.java:5902)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(IfxSqliConnect.java:2367)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(IfxSqliConnect.java:101)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:244)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:146)
    ... 15 more
```

Have somebody an idea?

Comment: Can't quite see why the table you query would have an effect on that error. `Connection not established` means the driver no longer has  a connection with the database. It was either closed (like an idle timeout) or it was never open. The table or SQL the driver is trying to prepare shouldn't matter (at that point). 
Try setting `IFX_SOC_KEEPALIVE=true` in the connection string, maybe it will help.